# Drupal 7, Ubercart, Product search by price range

Tags: 7, views, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart 3.x, Drupal7. Can anybody tell me how can I create a form for searching in products with price in specified interval? I.e. user should fill this form with minimum price in the interval and maximum price and after posting form he will see all suiting products.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of doing it:
One is using views and 2 price exposed filters, one with  "value bigger than" and the other one with "value smaller than".

The other solution is using [Search API ranges](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges) module.

> The Search API "ranges" module provides widgets for Search API range queries. Currently includes:
>
> - jQuery UI min/max slider.

To use it, you will need to use Facet API, follow a [tutorial here](http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/drupal-7-views-with-faceted-filters-without-apachesolr).

I hope this helps you